# PhpStorm xdebug waiting for connection

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have this problem and can´t resolve it.

When I click on debugg (xdebug) in PhpStorm (8.0.1) the debugger don´t show code. Only what happens is that my webbrowser open new empty tab and debugger show text "Waiting for connection from JetBrains IDE Support extension for Chrome (ID port 63343)"

This is my settings of xdebug:

(img) http://i61.tinypic.com/2q21gg1.png

And this is what PhpStorm show me (that it should be ok)

(img) https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkoAx.png

Port in PhpStorm debugger is ofcourse too 10000.
Firewall is off and antivir too.

I tried it in NetBeans and it faild too.

Do you know where is the problem please?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the whole window where it says *""Waiting for connection from JetBrains IDE Support extension for Chrome (ID port 63343)""*. So far it does not look like you are doing PHP debugging at all -- rather JavaScript one.

Comment: (img) http://i61.tinypic.com/2qb6vpi.png

Comment: As I have suspected you are doing JavaScript debug and not PHP one.

Comment: Some links to go through: **1)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/ **2)** https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: How did you find that it is this problem? I went throught the tutorial on jetbrains webpagea. do you knew where should i do it wrong please?

Comment: Because 1) PHP debug does not need to wait for any *"Support extension for Chrome"* 2) PHP Debug has different icon. Most likely you have initiated the debug from context menu. It should have more than 1 entry in submenu .. and you must have selected the wrong one. You may go to `Main Menu | Run | Edit Configurations...` and delete wrong entries and create one of correct type. In any case: link in #1 should have all the info on how to debug -- I had no issues with it.

Comment: It already works ! Thanks a lot :) now I understand, what i did wrong

Answer (score 5):

> "Waiting for connection from JetBrains IDE Support extension for Chrome (ID port 63343)"

This message tells that you are doing **JavaScript debug** instead of PHP debug.

Most likely you have initiated debug session from context menu. It should have more than 1 entry in submenu .. and you must have selected the wrong entry.

You may go to `Main Menu | Run | Edit Configurations...`, delete wrong entries and create one of correct type (or initiate again via context menu by choosing correct entry this time).

Some useful manuals for PHP debugging in PhpStorm to go through:

1. [Webinar recording: Debugging PHP with PhpStorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/)
2. [Zero-configuration Web Application debugging with Xdebug and PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm)